# content not display in Internet Explorer web browser

Tags: javascript, html, web

I'm trying to retrieve the IP address through javascript. This worked fine in Google Chrome and Firefox web browsers. But this does not work in the Internet Explorer and Edge.

What is the reason for not working this in internet explorer and Edge browsers?

```js
var RTCPeerConnection = /*window.RTCPeerConnection ||*/ window.webkitRTCPeerConnection || window.mozRTCPeerConnection;
if (RTCPeerConnection)(function() {
  var rtc = new RTCPeerConnection({
    iceServers: []
  });
  if (1 || window.mozRTCPeerConnection) {
    rtc.createDataChannel('', {
      reliable: false
    });
  };
  rtc.onicecandidate = function(evt) {
    if (evt.candidate) grepSDP("a=" + evt.candidate.candidate);
  };
  rtc.createOffer(function(offerDesc) {
    grepSDP(offerDesc.sdp);
    rtc.setLocalDescription(offerDesc);
  }, function(e) {
    console.warn("offer failed", e);
  });
  var addrs = Object.create(null);
  addrs["0.0.0.0"] = false;

  function updateDisplay(newAddr) {
    if (newAddr in addrs) return;
    else addrs[newAddr] = true;
    var displayAddrs = Object.keys(addrs).filter(function(k) {
      return addrs[k];
    });
    document.getElementById('list').textContent = displayAddrs.join(" or perhaps ") || "n/a";
  }

  function grepSDP(sdp) {
    var hosts = [];
    sdp.split('\r\n').forEach(function(line) {
      if (~line.indexOf("a=candidate")) {
        var parts = line.split(' '),
          addr = parts[4],
          type = parts[7];
        if (type === 'host') updateDisplay(addr);
      } else if (~line.indexOf("c=")) {
        var parts = line.split(' '),
          addr = parts[2];
        updateDisplay(addr);
      }
    });
  }
})();
else {
  document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = "<code>ifconfig| grep inet | grep -v inet6 | cut -d\" \" -f2 | tail -n1</code>";
  document.getElementById('list').nextSibling.textContent = "In Chrome and Firefox your IP should display automatically, by the power of WebRTCskull.";
}
```

```html
<div id="list"></div>
```

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#search=RTCPeerConnection

Comment: I didn't get that. what is the reason?

Comment: Are there any alternative ways to do that?

Comment: `In Chrome and Firefox your IP should display automatically, by the power of WebRTCskull.`

Comment: You can use a proxy.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't working in IE or pre-chromium Edge because those two browsers dont have support for the `RTCPeerConnection` API.

[CanIUse](https://caniuse.com/#search=RTCPeerConnection) gives you more information on browser support. Note that while Edge lists partial support, it doesn't support `RTCDataChannel` which you also seem to be using.

Comment: Are there any other alternative way to do display IP in the Internet explorer or Edge?

Comment: @usenanayake it would probably be better to ask that as a new question :)